# React nodejs web app not getting /pages on Heroku server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, github, heroku

I am facing some problem in my web app on heroku.

I'm unable to GET /pages eg. /signin or  /signup while running on heroku.

Here is my code on github.
https://github.com/tanmoysarkar/shoppingApp.git

Here is my link for heroku.
https://reactshoppingapp.herokuapp.com/

Its getting error canot GET /signin etc.

Any help would be very much needed on this issue.

Anyone can please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Curious, but why is this tagged "bitbucket"?

Comment: @JimRedmond thats my bad... edited .

Answer (score 0):

If I am right , you want to have a different url for login and signup as belows https://reactshoppingapp.herokuapp.com/signin

https://reactshoppingapp.herokuapp.com/signup .

To achive this you will have to add 2 more paths(GET) in your [server.js](https://github.com/tanmoysarkar/shoppingApp/blob/master/server.js) which will serve these pagesfor signin and signup ...

```
app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/signup.html'));
});

app.get('/signin', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/views/signin.html'));
    //signin.html is located in public/views/.. 
});
```

Note* : This is given that you have signup.html and login.html pages in your project in your public folder.

Comment: is signup.html or signup.js ?

Comment: It will be a HTML .. as your serve HTML to client not .js and this HTML page will have its own javascript code attached

Comment: And you may have to redeploy the new code on heroku

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163487/discussion-between-tanmoy-sarkar-and-damitj07).

Comment: @TanmoySarkar : If you have changed your code then you have to redeploy your code on heroku again for latest changes

Comment: I hope you might have fixed it.But I don't see the 2 new routes in your Server.js